# Do I need to lock an array that's being appended to in one thread and read from the beginning in another?

Tags: python, multithreading

This is similar to earlier questions, but a more specific situation.

- In **thread 1**, I am reading audio data. Each sample is appended to an array called `cum_samples`.
- In **thread 2**, a segment from the middle of `cum_samples` is read in preparation for frequency analysis. There is no possibility that I will be reading data from anywhere near the end of the array where new data is being appended by thread 1.

So is it necessary to lock `cum_samples`?

**thread 1**

```
inp = alsaaudio.PCM(alsaaudio.PCM_CAPTURE, alsaaudio.PCM_NORMAL)
while something is True:
    l, data = inp.read()
    cum_samples = b''.join((cum_samples,data))
```

**thread 2**

```
a = numpy.fromstring(cum_samples[2*job-8000:2*job], dtype = 'int16')
```

Comment: Why are you using multiple threads in the first place?

Comment: Because I'm sampling real time audio and I can't afford to miss any samples.  That's why I'm leery about locking the array in the first place. I've been given to understand that locks were fairly expensive in time required.
The question boils down to this: Is it safe to read data from the middle of an array with one thread while another thread is appending data to that same array?

Comment: It is safe but perhaps useless in your case.  Are you aware of the Python Global Interpreter Lock?  This means that Python cannot possibly interpret code in two threads at once.  So if thread 2 is doing something using Python code, thread 1 cannot do anything using Python code.  You would therefore be better off writing your input loop in C or C++ or something, and calling that once from Python (meaning once you call the reading function it does not return to Python).  But you can try with the code you have now--it may work well enough.